# Running Tomcat from windows 10 bash shell

Tags: bash, tomcat7, windows-10

I installed tomcat server on windows10 bash shell. Though it says apache is running.. its not opening admin panel in browser. Browser says 'Connection can't be reached'

Have someone tried this ever before? Please share your inputs.

Thank you

Comment: Please ask your sysadmin or ask at [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.

Comment: @Cyrus : Thats what I am doing.  This is on my personal computer. I wish to run some shell scripts which is blocked due to this reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you are referring to Bash for Windows (Ubuntu) on Windows 10.  Yes Tomcat server can be installed and run from Bash for Windows with no need to install Tomcat in the Windows environment.

First, you may want to check if any local server is running on Windows 10 port 8080 - the default port for Tomcat, or whatever port you are configuring Tomcat for.

Second, open BASH for Windows and install Java. I used Oracle Java JDK 8 (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and downloaded the tar.gz file.

Extract the tar.gz and copy to a standard directory like /usr/local/java or in the /opt/ directory for easy access.
Create JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME environment variables that link to your java location.

I also updated the alternatives to map java, javac, and javaws.  You can use this link to assist (http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre)

Then download the tar.gz of Tomcat. Again, I used Tomcat 8.5 for my scenario and extract the files to your chosen directory.

Last, run the startup script located in the bin folder of the tomcat extracted folder. You should have a working Tomcat version.

Use the curl command to validate - curl localhost:8080

If you want to change the admin privileges, edit the tomcat-users.xml file located in the conf folder within the extracted tomcat directory.

Access to the tomcat server can also be done through the Windows system and not just through the Bash for Windows CLI.

Hope this helps!