# How to check programmatically whether apache tomcat is running or not in python?

Tags: python, tomcat

Is there any way available to check the status of a apache tomcat server from another machine in python?

For example, A restful API is running in a machine with apache tomcat server in `8086` port.

[image]

Now, what I want is to check the status of the apache tomcat service of the specified machine from my pc programmatically in python.

Yes,I could check the machine is running or not through pinging by using `os.system` in python.

```
import os
hostname = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" #example
response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)

#and then check the response...
if response == 0:
    print hostname, 'is up!'
else:
    print hostname, 'is down!'
```

But, what I am interested in is that, is it possible to check the status of the service (**real_ip:8086/BotAPI**) in stead of the liveness of the machine, programmatically in python ?

Update: using paramiko I got the following traceback

```
channel.exec_command('ps -ef| grep tomcat')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#67>", line 1, in <module>
channel.exec_command('ps -ef| grep tomcat')
File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py", line 63, in _check
return func(self, *args, **kwds)
File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py", line 241, in exec_command
self._wait_for_event()
File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py", line 1197, in _wait_for_event
raise e
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Channel closed.
```

Comment: Can you ssh into the tomcat machine?

Comment: Yes. I could remotely logged in to the tomcat machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use fabric or paramiko to connect remotely to your tomcat machine and then check if the process is running

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('hostname', username='user', password='password')

transport = ssh.get_transport()
channel = transport.open_session()
channel.exec_command('ps -ef | grep tomcat')

status = channel.recv_exit_status()
```

Comment: Will it work in windows ? My tomcat machine is in windows 10.

Comment: w10? do you have that w10 shell? something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057339/running-tomcat-from-windows-10-bash-shell

Comment: No, It's running directly in netbeans.

Comment: well, you should check your firewall and user permissions

Comment: ssh.coneect works. but now channel.exec_command is not working... @lapinkoira

Comment: Is there any windows version of that ?

Comment: does it give an traceback?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538685/install-paramiko-on-windows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155239/discussion-between-w-jack-and-lapinkoira).